# Custom layout for different cell sizes in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I would like to use the new UICollectionView, but I'm not sure if it is possible to build the following:

[image]

As you can see, there are two different cell types. One is portrait, one is landscape. When I use the flow layout, it always creates rows of cells which are as high as the tallest cell. Not this kind of "fluid" layout I need.

Is it possible at all to achieve this kind of layout with a UICollectionView?

Has anyone done something like this before? Are there any samples? I already checked out many tutorials and the Class References ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check out https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout . Looks like something you can use for this

Answer (score 6):

It is possible with the FlowLayout, but you have to customize the FlowLayout Attributes.

Apple gives a good explanation, see [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html) scroll down to [**Specifying the Size of Items in the Flow Layout**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible using [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)

Comment: As I wrote, it is not. FlowLayout is a "line-based" layout. You either have fixed rows or fixed columns and a bit of variation on how you place your cells ... but it's not possible to get such a fluid layout.