# How to make UICollectionView width to be dependent of the screen size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a grid view and loaded it with data and width and height of 150x150. Since the width is 150px width, there is a huge gap between the cells, horizontally; regardless of "Min Spacing"; each row shows 2 cells (Tested on iPhone 6, 6+, and 5s; the gap is smaller on 5s but still). Therefore I want to create the cell size to be dependent of the phone size. On iPhone 6/6+ I want each row to have 3 cells while on iPhone 5s I want each row to show 2 cells. How can I achieve that? I am still investigating the issue on my own and see what kind of logic would fit in. Your help and advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting up constraints in Interface Builder for your collection view?

Comment: No I am using FlowLayout only. I will need to use them though; for scrollview to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `UICollectionView` layouts. Some information on the links below:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html

I think using Flow layout, you should be able to achieve what you wish, but you will need to add some code.

The following question will also give you some information:

- [Custom layout for different cell sizes in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450883/custom-layout-for-different-cell-sizes-in-uicollectionview)

Comment: Thank you! I am checking it out now.